# How can I tell if my timer is staying on schedule?

Tags: ios, swift

I understand it is reentrant and will not overrun itself, but I need to know if it's getting bogged down.

```
   init() {
            checkMoveTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.3, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                self.timeToMoveGroundTroups()
            })
        }

        func timeToMoveGroundTroups() {
            if gamePaused {
                return
            }

            for (_, vCache) in data.groundActive {
                data.groundObjects[vCache.index].next()
            }
        }
```

Comment: "I need to know if it's getting bogged down" Then save off the timestamp on every call to your action and compare the current timestamp with that.

Comment: Also please note you've created a retain cycle and major memory leak here.

Comment: Also please note you have failed to provide a `tolerance`. Doing so will actually make your timer work better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save off the timestamp on every call to your action (`timeToMoveGroundTroups`) into an instance property and (before you do so) compare the current timestamp with that. If the difference is too great, you can take action of some sort (log, `fatalError`, whatever).

Another approach would be to take advantage of the new `os_signpost` logging to graph what's happening in Instruments.

Two additional comments on the code you showed:

- Your timer will actually behave better if you provide a `tolerance`, typically about ten percent of the interval
- You have a retain cycle that's going to cause memory issues down the line; `self` needs to be declared `unowned` in your anonymous function

Comment: I like the timestamp idea and was looking into tolerances.  I had profiled it and didn't see any leaks.  unowned still confuses me, but I'm sure you're right and I'll try that too - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if !checkMoveTimer.valid {
 //TODO:
}
```

If I understood you correctly.

Comment: I think the timer is still "valid" even if it didn't meet the schedule, right?

Comment: @Voltan, No, it returns false if the timer has been invalidated and is no longer capable of firing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are times when it doesn't make it, but it keeps firing.  It says the system may enforce a maximum value for tolerance.  Possibly that's what is happening because it keeps running.  Does it enforce this IF I set a tolerance or does it enforce it even if I don't set a tolerance.